# Why I can't delete the rows in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to delete the rows with missing values in python and the code runs but with no effect whatsoever. The rows are not deleted.
I've added also a screenshot of my xls file.

This is how my code looks like:

```
  df = Pandas.read_excel('C:/Downloads/Report.xls')
  engine='python'
  new_df = df.dropna(inplace = true)
  puts new_df.to_string()
```

I've tried also with:
`new_df = df.dropna(axis=0, how="any", inplace=false)`
OR
`new_df = df.dropna()`

**IT DOES NOT DELETE THE ROWS.**

I get the following result:
Unnamed: 2
0    asset_number
1    WG0000000000
2    WG0000204381
3    WG0000204381
4    WG0000204381
5    WG0000204379
6    WG0000204379
7    WG0000204379
8    WG0000204366
9    WG0000204366
10   WG0000204366
11   WG0000204368
...[image: Report.xls]

Comment: `new_df = df.dropna()` or `df.dropna(inplace = true)`. Can't mix the two - then `new_df` would be `None`. `inplace=false` would not have worked because `false` is not the same as `False` in python (capitalization matters). `puts new_df.to_string()` is not even valid python - what's `puts`? also `new_df.to_string()` would have failed since `new_df` would have been `None` and you would have gotten an `AttributeError`. Please edit the post to include the actual code you're using so that we can help you. Also, is this in python or ruby (the question is tagged with both)?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I am running ruby but for my code I need pandas and python which are python code. ```puts``` is the ```print``` in ruby.
This is the actual code that I use:
```require 'pandas'
require 'win32ole'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Then(/^I delete all empty rows from the spreadsheet$/) do
  df = Pandas.read_excel('C:/Downloads/Report.xls')
  engine='python'
  new_df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
  puts new_df.to_string()
end```
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First fill the empty rows with NaN and then delete the na value as following:

```
nan_value = float("NaN")
Convert NaN values to empty string
df.replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Before dropping:-**

[image]

**After dropping:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @venkatesh ! It made the replacement but it still did NOT delete the rows. 
```  nan_value = Float('NaN', exception: false)
  #Convert NaN values to empty string
  df.replace("", nan_value, inplace=true)
  df.dropna(inplace=true)
  puts (df)```
The outcome:
 Photos                                         Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2
0    object                                          file_name  asset_number
1     asset                                                NaN  WG0000000000

Comment: Any other suggestions? Or how to delete the rows that include NaN? Thanks

Comment: # dropping the rows having NaN values 
df = df.dropna() 
  
# To reset the indices  
df = df.reset_index(drop = True) 
  
# Print the dataframe 
df
try this onc# dropping the rows having NaN values 
df = df.dropna() 
  
# To reset the indices  
df = df.reset_index(drop = True) 
  
# Print the dataframe 
df 
Try this Once
 @MrMihaiCostache

Comment: When I saved my files it adds also the index column - is there a way to suppress the index column and get only my initial 3 columns?  or just save the result to my original file without the NaN rows?

Comment: df.to_csv('',index=False)